# Pause music when switching to another page in php

Tags: php, flash

I like to pause music when switching to another page from home page & on returning back we should resume the music as it was before. It shouldn't need to restart the music again when I get back to home page.

We are using flashplayer found from this site:
http://flashnifties.com/products/nifty-audio-player/documentation/

However we have not found any script which fulfill our need.

Please help me if anyone has the solution of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The critical part of this problem is that you are reloading the page, which completely resets the Flash player within it. You are left with two options:

Implement your site as a single page application and use ajax to refresh the content. This means that the Flash player will not be reloaded when the user needs more content (this is what we do on our site).

-or-

Use a frameset, with player loaded in one frame, and rest of website in the other. This is a bad choice of architecture... [frames are evil](http://www.google.com/search?q=frames%20evil&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can pause with this:

```
audioPlayer.pauseAudio()
```

I would add this javascript to the button or object that changes to a new url (page). This listens for an action and does

```
document.getElementById('newPageButton').onclick = function() {
    //interact with the flash "audioPlayer.pauseAudio();", cache song time location.
    //go to next page code
}
```

you'll probably need to write your own actionscript to save the location of were the song was paused at. Looking at the documentation there isn't a way to see exactly were the song was paused.

After you figure that out, store the location on some sort of caching. Load that caching when you go back to the page. Though looking at the documentation again, it looks like you'll need to write some actionscript to get resuming at a specific time working.

This might not be the best flash player for what you wish to achieve.

Comment: Which Flash player would you like to do best to my need?